# Уаление пользователя, который содержит комментарии, которые содержат пользователя

Tags: jpa, hibernate, java, mysql

Доброго времени суток.
Имеются сущности `User`, `Comment`.
`User` содержит `List` из `Comment`'ов. `Comment`'ы хранят `User`'a, который их создал:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments;

}

@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}
```

Всё лишнее из кода убрал.
При попытке удалить `User` выкидывает исключение:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ruslan`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `FK_6o4459xu10e3y7xtula720aer` FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

Помогите исправить.

Comment: попробуйте так: 

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781080/cyclic-relationships-in-hibernate

а вообще гуглить: `java hibernate cyclic references`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получается замкнутый круг: пользователь содержит комментарий, комментарий содержит того же пользователя. Разорвите этот круг. Пусть например только пользователь содержит свои комментарии, а у каждого комментария будет только идентификатор пользователя как атрибут.

Comment: Для такого случая ваш ответ подходит, но это сильно упрощённая модель. На самом деле у меня есть ещё и класс Book, который содержит комментарии на него. При этом нужно реализовать нормальное удаление как Book, так и User, чтобы при этом всё остальное, связанное с ними, удалялось. Кроме как ручной ходьбы по ссылкам и их установления в null пока решения не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню в hibernate можно настроить режим удаления записи таблицы. Не помню точно как там всё это обзывается, но смысл заключается в следующем: есть режим при котором удаляя одну из записей удаляются все зависимые записи, а есть режим при котором записи удаляются независимо друг от друга(т.е. логику удаления зависмых записей Вы должны реализовать самостоятельно). Т.е. Ваша задача покопаться в настройках hibernate, а затем реализовать логику удаления записей.

Comment: Вот как раз этот режим я найти и не могу. Решил пока проблему установлением при удалении ссылки на user в null.

Answer (score 0):

`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, **orphanRemoval=true**)` - JPA 2.0 в JPA 1 - этого нету